# Decrease Space Before and After Section Titles (titlesec alternative)

Tags: spacing, titlesec, vertical

I using `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}` and want to decrease the spacing before `section` and `subsection`.

[image]

I have already tried `\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}`, but it breaks the formatting of the `subsubsection` title.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're submitting to an IEEE journal, then you probably shouldn't be messing with the spacing of titles, since the class is designed with its own sizes in mind.  That being said, you can use `titlesec`, but you will need to use its formatting commands for each section yourself. You can't just use one of the package options, which assume you are using the standard classes.   Since the `IEEE` classes don't define a `subparagraph` titling level, but `titlesec` assumes one to be present, you need to define one before loading `titlesec`. Here's a minimal example which narrows the spacing and retains the IEEE format.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\def\subparagraph{} % because IEEE classes don't define this, but titlesec assumes it's present
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*1}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*1}{*1}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\itshape}{\thesubsubsection)}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{\parindent}{0pt}{*1}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you; this is what I needed, except I added a ```:``` to the end of the ```subsubsection``` title